# For any matrix norm, is it true $||A|| \le \max|a_{ij}|\cdot ||(1)||$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $|| \cdot ||$ be a matrix norm on $m \times n$ matrices, which is not assumed to be submultiplicative. Is it true that $||A|| \le \max|a_{ij}|\cdot ||(1)||$ where $(1)$ denotes the matrix with all entries equal to 1? I tried to use triangle inequality but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106305/on-matrix-norm-equivalence#106321

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is incorrect when $mn>1$. A simple counter-example: for $A=(a_{ij})$, let 
$$\|A\|=|a_{11}|+\sum_{ij}|a_{ij}-a_{11}|.$$

**Remark**: When $m=n>1$, even if $\|\cdot\|$ is submultiplicative, the conclusion is still incorrect . To provide a counter-example, you may choose $\|\cdot\|$  as defined in $(4)$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367752/matrix-norm-set-2/367998#367998) with $P=\lambda\cdot(1)$, where $\lambda>1$ is a large constant determined by the norm $\|\cdot\|'$ in $(4)$.